VS Code 1.90 PowerShell is escaping ANSI escape codes like "\x1b[0m"
VS Code terminal
I'm talking about these characters: \x1b[0m \x1b7\x1b[1000C\x1b[32D\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b0\x3b119\x3b194m\x1b[0m\x1b[48\x3b2\x3b0\x3b119\x3b194m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b255\x3b255\x3b255m  pwsh \x1b[0m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b0\x3b119\x3b194\x3b49m\x1b[7m\x1b[0m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b76\x3b175\x3b80m\x1b[0m\x1b[48\x3b2\x3b76\x3b175\x3b80m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b255\x3b255\x3b255m  100 \x1b[0m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b76\x3b175\x3b80\x3b49m\x1b[7m\x1b[0m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b46\x3b149\x3b153m\x1b[0m\x1b[48\x3b2\x3b46\x3b149\x3b153m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b17\x3b17\x3b17m 08:55:45 \x1b[0m\x1b[38\x3b2\x3b46\x3b149\x3b153m\x1b[0m\x1b8
I've tried this accepted solution.
Set VS Code "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false and enabled "shell_integration": true in oh-my-posh configuration file. That didn't work for me.

That should work perfectly on Linux or a Mac. The sequence [0m is part of the VT100 sequence to control the terminal (eg. change text color) and works on all operating systems except Windows. You should configure VSCode to use a Linux style terminal like gitbash or WSL (obviously once you start using WSL your programs are no longer running on Windows but a virtual Linux running in Windows). Sorry I can't help you to actually solve the problem since I don't use Windows

I do have gitbash configured to run in VS Code as well. It's just a habit, and it was working fine until latest VS Code upgrade. So I might have to switch now. Thanks for advise.

a temporary workaround is - simply type pwsh.exe (for PowerShell 7) or powershell.exe (for PowerShell 5) in the terminal, and it will launch a brand new, yet identical terminal in the current working directory -
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/211922#issuecomment-2165088767

This is probably a case of the bug described in issue ticket Terminal in VSCode Insiders not able to display special characters #211922.
The fix has been made in Encode all chars 0x00-0x1f #215452 and is in the 1.90.2 release.
Some people say they were able to work around the issue by replacing the PowerShell shell integration script for 1.90 with an older version like this one. The path to the file to replace is in ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\browser\media\shellIntegration.ps1.
Another user said that as a workaround, they could start a subshell (run pwsh.exe / powershell.exe) and the subshell wouldn't have this issue.

Like mentioned in the answer, a fix of this is scheduled for next month of VsCode. A way to get this fix sooner is to try in out VsCode Insiders , which offers nightly builds from here :
https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/
It is not perfect, since this edition of VsCode has not added the same extensions as you have in VsCode, but using Vs Code - Insiders is a workaround for this annoying bug of Powershell terminal window.

I was searching for solutions to this problem and found that a very easy temporary fix is to type pwsh.exe for powershell 7 or powershell.exe for powershell 5 in the terminal. That worked for me, and I plan to work like that until the fix is rolled out.
This was suggested by this user:
[source]: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/211922#issuecomment-2165088767
